# How to fetch and display a specific index in a JSON file using a Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, fetch

I am currently using fetch in javascript to obtain information from another site into my own. The issue I am having is, I am using a loop to display all of the indexes of the JSON file into my site. I actually want to get specific indexes to show, not all of them, for example, index 2,4 and 6.

Here is my code so far:

```
window.addEventListener("load", (event)=>{
const requestURL = 'https://byui-cit230.github.io/weather/data/towndata.json';

fetch(requestURL)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (jsonObject) {
    const towns = jsonObject['towns'];
    for (let i = 0; i < towns.length; i++ ) {

        let towninfo = document.createElement('section');
        let townname = document.createElement('h2');
        townname.textContent = towns[i].name;
        towninfo.appendChild(townname);
        document.querySelector('div.weathertowns').appendChild(towninfo);
        
    }
  });
})
```

This displays all of the towns in reference, but I only want to display the title of 3 specific ones. Any suggestions on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (event)=>
  {
  const requestURL      = 'https://byui-cit230.github.io/weather/data/towndata.json'
    ,   divWeathertowns = document.querySelector('div.weathertowns')
    ;
  fetch(requestURL)
  .then( response=>response.json() )
  .then( jsonObject=>
    {
    const towns = jsonObject['towns']
      ;
    for ( let i of [2,4,6] )
      {
      let towninfo = document.createElement('section') 
        , townname = document.createElement('h2')
        ;
      townname.textContent = towns[i].name;
      towninfo.appendChild(townname);
      divWeathertowns.appendChild(towninfo);
      }
    });
  })
```

```html
<div class="weathertowns"></div>
```